# Can't load /root/.rnd into RNG : where can I find it, or how to create it?

Tags: openssl, random-number-generator

I'm trying to setup a VPN server with OpenVPN, on an Ubuntu Server 18.04, and I want to use EasyRSA to build my PKI CA.

So, while connected as root, I launch the EasyRSA scripts which I copied to `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa`. Everything works fine with `./clean-all`and `./build-dh`, but when I try to launch `./pkitool --initca`, I get this error :

```
Can't load /root/.rnd into RNG
140171234709952:error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file:../crypto/rand/randfile.c:88:Filename=/root/.rnd
```

In the openssl confing file (`/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf`), I find this line which indicates why it tries to reach `/root/.rnd` :

```
RANDFILE    = $ENV::HOME/.rnd
```

From what I read and understood online, `.rnd` is a seed that openssl uses to generate random numbers. The strange thing is : even though I get this error, the RSA private key IS generated by the script. I just fear that it is not random, since it lacks a seed.

So my problem is : this file doesn't exist on my system, it is not in `/root/`, not in `/home/user/` which is my only other user, and `find / -name ".rnd"` returns nothing. Even `find / -iname "*.rnd"` returns nothing.

And I don't even know how I can create it, or if I understood this all wrong.

Comment: See the answer from @Biddut below that addresses efficiently the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> even though I get this error, the RSA private key IS generated by the script

The file doesn't need to exist; OpenSSL creates it on its own after the first time.

> I just fear that it is not random, since it lacks a seed.

The OS provides the seed using its own RNG through `/dev/urandom` or through system calls such as `getentropy()` or `CryptGenRandom()`. There's no need for you to provide anything extra.

I would guess that the `.rnd` file is more or less a leftover from the days when the OS lacked a good CSPRNG, possibly when the Linux `/dev/urandom` was considered poor-quality (and `/dev/random` produced data very slowly due to "entropy accounting"). Now it is no longer the case, and relying entirely on a seed stored on some file in your homedir would actually be *less* secure.

Answer (score 12):

Create one in expected path

```
cd ~/; openssl rand -writerand .rnd
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Solved my problem (Linux Mint 20.0)

Comment: Excellent solution

Answer (score 4):

> OpenSSL creates it on its own after the first time.

Actually, it doesn't, no matter how many times I launch the script or if I just try to use the `openssl rand` command directly, it is never created.

But you were right : I generated two keys to check if they were different and they were.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Remark the RANDFILE line in /etc/ssl/openssl.conf
[more](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/wazuh/wazuh/3395/496449901)

Comment: This should be the accepted solution.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Like this, @LobsterBaz, I had the same problem, Google lead me here and saw the same query that I was searching for. So I left and continued googling and I understood the problem, solved it, search back in superuser.com and posted the solution. That was the "making of the comment above". Sorry that it didn't work for you, my be you can post your answer for our community!!!